# Inheritance with static method doesn't work

Tags: typescript

I have following **javascript** code:

```
class TodoContainer extends Container {
    static mapper(state) {
        return {
            items: state.todo.items
        };
    }
...
```

And its superclass Container:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    static connect() {
        this.__connected = true;

        return ReactRedux.connect(
            (state) => {
                let mapper = this['mapper'];
                return mapper ? mapper(state) : {}; // compile error on "mapper(state)"
            }
        )(this);
    }

    static mapper() {
        return {};
    }
...
```

In connect() method of Container class, it either calls mapper(state) method in subclass TodoContainer, or return {} at `return mapper ? mapper(state) : {};`

**I am trying to make it work on Typescript,**

But I get a following error at `mapper(state)` in static connect():

```
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. ts(2554)
```

How do I solve this? It should call static mapper(state) in TodoContainer when there is a value in `let mapper = this['mapper'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared mapper() without any arguments in the base class, hence the compile error. An easy solution would be to add an optional parameter to Container.mapper.

The cleanest way to do this is to mark mapper as `abstract` in the base class, and implement it in derived classes.